# Is it possible to tweak Ember blueprints

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When writing acceptance tests for our application, we use ember generate to stub out the test (`ember generate acceptance-test <name>`).

The next step is typically to modify the generated test to call [ember-simple-auth-testing's](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-testing) `authenticateSession()` in the module block (and most likely perform some setup with [ember-data-factory-guy](https://github.com/danielspaniel/ember-data-factory-guy)).

What I would like to do is make a slight tweak to the acceptance-test blueprint's template, however I can't seem to find any documentation on how to extend blueprints.

Does anyone know if any such documentation exists, or how I might go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't extend one, but you can overwrite one. From [the Ember CLI docs on blueprints](http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#blueprints):

> Blueprints in your project’s directory take precedence over those packaged with ember-cli. This makes it easy to override the built-in blueprints just by generating one with the same name.

So just run the following command, then modify the templates as you see fit:

```
ember generate blueprint acceptance-test
```

You can find the Ember CLI acceptance-test blueprint [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-legacy-blueprints/tree/master/blueprints/acceptance-test). That should be a good reference for writing yours. Also be sure to read the entire section on blueprints in the documentation that I linked to — that should get you familiar with how to write a blueprint.

There is an [issue under ember-cli/blueprint](https://github.com/ember-cli/blueprint/issues/2) about the possibility of supporting 'extend' for blueprints.

Answer (score 4):

You can't extend a blueprint via inheritance, but you can copy the code for that blueprint into your own app and modify it:

Steps:

1. create a top-level folder called `blueprints` (ie the same level as your app folder).
2. open your `node_modules` folder, find `ember-cli`, and find the folder for the blueprint you are trying to "extend". I use quotes because we are merely going to override. If the blueprint you're looking for isn't present there, it's probably been moved to [ember-cli-legacy-blueprints](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-legacy-blueprints/).
3. Copy and paste the `acceptance-test` folder into your newly create `blueprints` folder
4. If you are just wanting to modify the generated template for the test, find the file: `acceptance-test/files/tests/acceptance/__name__-test.js` in your `blueprints` folder and modify it.

Calling `ember generate acceptance-test` will now use your `blueprints` version

Comment: Note you will need to replace all `require` statements with something like `../../node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/fs-extra`.